# accepts_nested_attributes_for - belongs_to, has_many, fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any possible way to use nested_attributes_for in the way show below?
Basically I want to create a person, one or more cars and add details to each car.   This is just a mock up, not a very realistic example.  I get snagged when trying to build the details for the car as it hasn't been created yet.

Models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :cars
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :car
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :details
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details
end

class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
end
```

Form:

```
form_for @person do |f|
  #fields
  f.fields_for :car do |car|
    #fields
    car.fields_for :details |detail|
      =detail.text_field :content
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at that http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast